# map reduce complexity

Tags: clojure, complexity-theory, jvm-languages

Lets suppose that i have this input: a list of list

> (def  list-of-list-3 **(list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6) (list 7 8 9)) )**
>
> (map #(reduce * %1)  list-of-list3 )

**The map-reduce has a O(n^2) complexity in this case?**

**is map-reduce translated as two nested for ?**

So when i run the above example on the clojure REPL, the complexity time seems like  O(n).

when i duplicate the input size ( list-of-list-6 (list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6) ( list 7 8 9) (list 8 2 3) (list 9 8 1) (list 7 6 4)) ) the time increase in a linear way, not quadratic.

Can anyone say why ?

thanks in advance

Comment: It would be a good idea to remove 'java' from the tag list.  The implementation looks like a LISP variant.

Comment: Yeah David, i will. This variant is called Clojure, another JVM Language. Its really cool ! My next languages will be scala or clojure. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The map-reduce has a `O(n^2)` complexity in this case?

Impossible to say, unless you tell us what `n` corresponds to in the `list-of-list-3` expression.

By the way, `O(n^2)` or `O(n*n)` is quadratic complexity, not exponential complexity.  Exponential complexity it `O(e^n)`.

> when i [double] the input size
>
> ```
> ( list-of-list-6 (list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6) ( list 7 8 9) 
>                        (list 8 2 3) (list 9 8 1) (list 7 6 4)) )
> ```
>
> the time increase in a linear way, not exponential.

From this, I surmise that the `n` is supposed to be the length of the outer list.  If so, then the `reduce` is actually `O(n)` not `O(n^2)`.  To get quadratic growth, you would need to define `list-of-list-6` as:

```
( list-of-list-6 (list (list 1 2 3 4 5 6) (list 4 5 6 1 3 2) 
                       (list 7 8 9 1 2 3) (list 8 2 3 2 3 4) 
                       (list 9 8 1 2 3 4) (list 7 6 4 5 6 7)) )
```

Comment: yes stephen. n is the size of the outer list. m for inner-list. the complexity is n*m. in the worst case the Big-O is quadratic.

Comment: disagreed, please see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

It's not O(n^2), it's roughly O(n*m) where n is the no of lists and m is the length of them.
There will be other factors as well to do with the lengths of various numbers. Do it by hand and time yourself to see why!